# ☸️ Saving the file after performing job k8s

Tags: kubernetes

After reading a lot of manuals, I still don't understand if it is possible to save a file to the host after performing a job or a cronjob.

My Job got PVC and PV like that:

```
volumes:
  - name:  name1
    persistentVolumeClaim:
      claimName: name2
```

and:

```
volumeMounts:
  - name: save-file
    mountPath: /mnt/dir
```

Let's say I'm running a script that saves the output to a file:

```
command: ["dosomething.py"]
args: [" --save-to-file output.txt"]
```

Is there some way to save it to the host or send it somewhere?

Comment: When you say "the host", which one?  If a Job runs somewhere in a cluster with dozens of nodes, how will you find the right node after the fact?

Comment: node affinity :-)

Answer (score 2):

Mount the volume for container and give a mount path-

```
  volumeMounts:
    - name: "name1"
      mountPath: "/var/www/html"
```

The container can save file to it.
Read more details here - https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-persistent-volume-storage/#create-a-persistentvolume

Comment: forget to put this part, now I changed my issue

Comment: kind: PersistentVolume
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: owasp-zap-py
  labels:
    type: local
spec:
  storageClassName: owasp-zap-py
  capacity:
    storage: 2Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  hostPath:
    path: "/data/owasp-zap-py"

Comment: Any file saved in /mnt/dir by the container will be found in /data/owasp-zap-py

Comment: I have created a new issue to get this functionality without using a PersistentVolume: github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/111045 Please support me and give this ticket a thumbs up.